# Don't understand error message

Tags: sudo, software-sources, synaptics

malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:stevenpusser.listn(type) 
E:The list of sources could not be read. Now I can't issue any sudo commands. This message is greek to me. I can't find /etc/apt/sources.list.d  How can I fix this problem?  I was trying to add the palemoon browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `terminal` do:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*pusser*.list
```

and/or

```
grep -i pusser /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

on any **found** filenames, do:

```
more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/found_filename_here.list
```

Edit that output into your question, and then send a comment to @heynnema, and I'll take a look for you.

**Update #1:**

I asked that you put the output of the above commands as an edit of your original question, as trying to read that data in comments is difficult.

But right now you should be able to do the following...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:stevenpusser.list
```

Comment: ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*pusser*.list
cannot access ‘etc/apt/sources.d/*pusser*.list
grep -i pusser /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:stevenpusser.list:http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/stevenpusser/xbuntu_16.04//
more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/filename_here.list
more: stat of  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/filename_here.list failed: no such file or directory
to @heynnema,

Comment: ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
google-chrome.list.save webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list      Can I just remove the last 2 files in this directory? @heynnema
home:stevenpusser.list webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
home:stevenpusser.list.save webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-xenial.list

Comment: ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
google-chrome.list.save webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list     
home:stevenpusser.list webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save      Can I just remove the last 2 files in this directory? @heynnema   I was trying to add the Y-PPA-manager after that.